# Getting Illegal string offset Warning while fetching data

Tags: php, mysql

```
$cq = "SELECT * FROM salescard WHERE custid = '$custid'";
$rq = mysqli_query($conn,$cq);
if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($rq, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$edate =$c['expdate'];
$ono = $c['orderno'];
$cno = $c['cardno'];
$c = $c['cvv'];
$email = $c['email'];
$no = $c['no'];

}
```

I am fetching data from the table and echoing the variables fetched above.

All the variables are echoed properly expect $email and $no.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'email' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\admin\viewsales\card.php on line 94

Warning: Illegal string offset 'no' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\admin\viewsales\card.php on line 95
```

All i know is this warning has something to do with variable being defined where an array is expected.

Only two variables are showing the error and rest are fetching properly
How can i make this work properly?

**EDIT**

i surely have these two columns in my salescard table and i was able to store data into it from another form.

```
$email = $c['email'];
$no = $c['no'];
```

These are the lines 94 and 95

And i want to display the data here

```
<div class="form-group half left clear">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $email;?>" name="email" />
  <label class="control-label" for="input">Email Address</label><i 
class="bar"></i>
</div>

 <div class="form-group half right">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $no;?>" name="no" />
  <label class="control-label" for="input">Contact number</label><i 
class="bar"></i>       
 </div>
```

Comment: do you have `email,no` columns in your `salescard` table? Also where you are using these variables can you show that code (like 94,95 lines)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite $c in line 93, and make it a string.

```
$c = $c['cvv'];
```

Should be:

```
$cvv = $c['cvv'];
```

Comment: This also stresses the importance of having **meaningful** variable names. `$array` or `$data` would suit so much more than `$c`.

Comment: damn!! these minor mistakes really costing me some time .. saving time with short variable names did backfired .. anyway thanks :)

Comment: @Arun it's pretty terrifying that you appear to be processing credit card data with code that looks lile like `... WHERE custid = '$custid'";`  Variable interpolation into SQL queries is, for all practical purposes, *never* an acceptable practice.  This code seems vulnerable to SQL injection.  If you learned this from a book, you should set the book on fire.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. I'll admit that it is not clear who provides $custid. But  without that information your comment seems harsh. If the source for $custid can't be trusted, and  $custid is not sanitzed, you're absolutely correct.

Comment: @jh1711 agreed, it did sound harsh.  It was a reaction to the notion of "saving time" (though I didn't explicitly say so) --building queries like this is "easy" but the danger of such practices can't really be overstated.   Even concepts like "trusted" and "sanitized" are not really sufficient justifications for concatenation, as subsequent refactoring can undo those things and the undoing can go unnoticed.  Good eye on the answer, btw.  Seeing the magic string "cvv" was what initially set me off.  CVV is never supposed to be stored in a database.  You discard that after authorization.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot There is enough security provided that only authorized persons can access this page and fetch the data .. But anyways i would like to know if u have any better recommendation for me on this .. And yeah the code is sanitized

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot actually the application for which i am using this is not what you are assuming .. well thanks for the valuable info though

Comment: @Arun see http://bobby-tables.com/php/ for some PHP-specific suggestions. The web site gets its name from an old gag based on a student named `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;-- `... in a query `WHERE (... AND student_name = '$student')`, this "name" extrapolates to `WHERE (... AND student_name = 'Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;-- '` and you see the potential problem, there.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Will look into it .. Thanks for the valuable advice